# Do iTunes backups store file modification times?

Tags: python, ios, iphone, itunes, backups

I have an iPhone. With a USB connection, I can use tools such as Macroplant iExplorer or Apple's Image Capture to transfer files from the iPhone to my computer. When I transfer files over USB, the file modification times are preserved.

```
crisp:test2 work$ stat -F IMG_3134.jpg
-rw------- 1 work staff 2039650 Jun  7 11:21:38 2015 IMG_3134.jpg
```

I also have many old iTunes backups, which iTunes stores here:

~/Library/Application Support/MobileSync/Backup

iTunes encodes the backups using some voodoo, and so tools such as iPhone Backup Extractor or the python tools by Padraig Kennedy (http://supercrazyawesome.com) are required to unpack the system files from the backup archive.

The files these tools produce do not preserve file modification times, because as they unpack the archives, they create new files.

```
crisp:test2 work$ stat -F IMG_3796.JPG
-rw------- 1 work staff 942653 Sep 25 17:31:33 2015 IMG_3796.JPG
```

My question is, does iTunes preserve file modification times in these backup archives, either in the archive itself, or in some sort of database? Is it a shortcoming of these tools that they do not preserve/restore the timestamps? Is there a way to extract the mdbackup files that preserves this data?

Comment: I don't see how your question is related to a *programming problem*. What iTunes does should be probably asked on Ask Different or Super User.

Comment: Well, I'm hoping to understand how to work with these backup files, from someone who has experience extracting files from iTunes backups. I could write a bash script to touch the files, but I need to know if the data exists in the first place.